# Play/Stop animation/animator on instantiated object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a unity game and basically, I have a prefab with a sprite inside it. I created an animation attached to that sprite.

```
FrogPrefab
    |__ FrogSprite
```

I created a script with a public field "prefab" where I pass my prefab.

My question is, how can I stop and play this animation from my script.

I instantiated my prefab from my start method...

```
public GameObject gameCharacterPrefab;

private GameObject frog;

void start() {
    frog = (GameObject)Instantiate(gameCharacterPrefab, objectPoolPosition, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

I'm trying to do something like that...

```
frog.animation.stop();
```

appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that the function should be called `Start` not `start`. Maybe this is a typo in the question but it's worth mentioning.

Use `GetComponent` to get the `Animator` or `Animation` component. If the animation is a child of the prefab then use `GetComponentInChildren`.

**If using the `Animator` component:**

```
public GameObject gameCharacterPrefab;
private GameObject frog;
Vector3 objectPoolPosition = Vector3.zero;
Animator anim;
```

Instantiate the prefab

```
frog = (GameObject)Instantiate(gameCharacterPrefab, objectPoolPosition, Quaternion.identity);
```

Get the `Animator` component

```
anim = frog.GetComponent<Animator>();
```

Play animation state

```
anim.Play("AnimStateName");
```

Stop animation

```
anim.StopPlayback();
```

---

---

**If using the `Animation` component:**

```
public GameObject gameCharacterPrefab;
private GameObject frog;
Vector3 objectPoolPosition = Vector3.zero;
Animation anim;
```

Instantiate the prefab

```
frog = (GameObject)Instantiate(gameCharacterPrefab, objectPoolPosition, Quaternion.identity);
```

Get the `Animation` component

```
anim = frog.GetComponent<Animation>();
```

Play animation name

```
anim.Play("AnimName");
```

Stop animation

```
anim.Stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

For playing animation we can use Play() but for stopping the animation the Stop method is become obsolete in Unity 2019 or higher versions. So, For disable animation we can use enable flag and set it to false.

```
//For playing the animation
frog.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(); 
or
frog.GetComponent<Animator>().enable = true; 

//For stop the animation
frog.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
```